# With before_filter, is it possible to exclude a mounted engine's actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app, I am mounting an external engine. I have a `before_filter` in my `ApplicationController`, and I need to exclude some of the engine's actions from this filter.

Typically, I would use `skip_before_filter` in the respective controller, but I would rather not touch the engine code itself since it is not mine.

Is there a way to do this?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :authorize, :except => [:engine/setup] # something like this?
  ...
```

Thanks,

PJ

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to orien's answer, you need to specify the specific controller within the engine, or just the `ApplicationController`:

```
EngineController::ApplicationController.class_eval do
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:setup]
end
```

Also, if you want the filter skip to be reloaded on each request in development mode:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  EngineController::ApplicationController.class_eval do
    skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:setup]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following to an initializer - eg `config/initializers/engine.rb`

```
EngineController.class_eval do
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:setup]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just inherit the engine controller you want from a new controller of your own and then override the actions for which you want to skip the before filter and just calll **super** in it. In that controller, call skip_before_filter with the name of your action (which is also the name of the parent engine controller action).

```
class MyController < EngineController
    skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:setup]

    def setup
        super
    end
end
```

Not totally sure but I think this will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry it took me so long... This was not an option for us: this engine has a lot of controllers (<>30). We would need to do this too many times. So I did not try. But anyway I am not sure it would work to be honest: when we load an URL pointing to the engine, how will Rails know to "ask" these new controllers instead of the original, engine ones directly?

Comment: Because the controllers you have in your app directory have the priority when routing somewhere.